# Monitoring rectangular node usage

Tags: anylogic

I move a batch of agents to a node, where they are unbatched. Once the unbatched agents occupy this node, the node is not available for other batches of agents to move there, so I remove that node from a collection of available nodes, AvailableNodes.(There are about 50 nodes total). Each unbatched agent has a parameter that is the node it has been moved to.  The question is how to add back a node to AvailableNodes once all unbatched agents have been moved from that node. Do I have a variable associated with each node that I increment or decrement as agents enter/exit the node? If so, how do I associate a unique variable with a node? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Oh you are walking in muddy waters with bad practices... your nodes should belong to a resourcepool, meaning that instead of a node, you should have an agent with a node in it... That way you don't need any collection at all.

Another option is to create a small class that will have the node and the availability... and maybe the number of agents currently present in that node. Just create a new class, and add these 3 variables. Then on the start of the model you add instances of that class to the collection availableNodes and you can then just do theClass.numberOfAgents+=1 or -=1 depending on wether agents are being added to the node. To find an available agent you can then do `TheClass x=findFirst(availableNodes, a->a.numberOfAgents==0);` and then you can send your agents to `x.node;`

There is also a possibility continuing to do what you are doing... but I won't even go there because it will be a mess.

Comment: "Oh you are walking in muddy waters with bad practices..." Well said, good answers :-)

Comment: Thanks Felipe. So with the resourcepool, how can you resolve the issue of wanting the batch agent to seize the resource, then somehow have the last element in that batch be able to free that resource? IOW, how does last element know it's last?

Comment: there are many ways of doing that... one of them is just to release when the node is empty... Another one is to count until all of them are out...